# How to pass value using string interpolation in angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have a list of posts and each post has post comment form , i am trying to send post id with comment form for each post but it's not working..

i have tried to use

```
  <form class="comment-form inline-items" [formGroup]="form2" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitComment()">

    <div class="post__author author vcard inline-items">
      <img src="{{user.photo}}" alt="author">

        <h1>{{post.id}}</h1> <!-- it's working here -->

      <div class="form-group with-icon-right ">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="" name="body" formControlName="body"></textarea>

        <input  type="text"  value={{post.id}}  name="id" formControlName="id"/> <!-- it's not working here -->



      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-md-2 btn-primary">Post Comment</button>


  </form>
```

I have expected to send the post id with the comment but its sending null value

Comment: what about `[value]="post.id"` or `value="{{ post.id }}"` <-- with quotes?

Comment: @JasonWhite same thing its still sending null value

Comment: can you put together a stackblitz.com demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @JasonWhite i am sorry but i am using an external api to fetch data

Comment: you could use mock data

Comment: Try using `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[value]` in your input

Comment: @Jojofoulk i am using formcontrolname

Comment: You don't need `value` attribute, if you setup your reactive form correctly all you need to do to get the value is `form2.value` suggest you take a read on https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @penleychan how come! I have list of posts and each post has form i need to send the post id that i am trying to comment on !

Comment: Again, have a read on how reactive form works, you don't seem to have a full grasp of it yet. Also you only provided HTML template without any `typescript` file for your component for any of us to fully understand how you setup your reactive form.

Comment: @JasonWhite here you go 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsfy7o

Comment: @penleychan here you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsfy7o

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8xilf) I made.
You can see the `id` being passed through in the submit function and (optionally) changes in the input field being reflected in the model.

Let me know if that's what you were after

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the approach you are trying to use is different from mine.
kindly check the link below for my typescript file to understand what i am trying to do

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsfy7o